# Modify Trackpad Right click via command line without logout

Tags: trackpad, preferences

Is it possible to toggle the the preference setting under Trackpad labeled Secondary Click without logging out and in, so that I can toggle two-finger right-click for the builtin trackpad?

I found the command

`defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.enableSecondaryClick -bool true`

But that doesn't seem to work. Toggling the checkbox does also seem to change `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist` when system preferences is closed, but using `defaults` to change that doesn't help either.

I'd like to toggle it multiple times in one session without going through system preferences, so logging out and back in isn't preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to reload the kext for it

`sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTrackpad.kext` to disable it.

Change `kextunload` to `kextload` to re-enable it.

Now create a script from above so you can run it with one click.

Sorry, that was for the external trackpad.

For the internal that would be to unload:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch; sudo touch /system/library/extensions ; exit
```

Comment: When I run `kextunload`, i get the message `(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTrackpad not found for unload request.`, which seems to mean that the kext wasn't loaded in the first place. Loading the kext after this runs without comment, but doesn't seem to change anything. I'm using 10.9.5 if that helps